# Wheel rotation frequency from accelerometer data

Tags: accelerometer

Need to calculate the **wheel rotation frequency** from the accelerometer data-set.

What I have :

1. Acc. data from 2 different wheels of a car

Need guidance to approach towards the solution.

Used the plot function to find the similarity between 2 different wheels.

Answer (score -1):

To calculate the rotation frequency of a wheel based on accelerometer data, you need a systematic approach that involves analyzing the accelerometer's time-series data to identify patterns or periodicity corresponding to wheel rotations.

What you have:

Data from accelerometers on two different wheels of a car.
A need for guidance to approach the solution.
You've used a plot function to find similarities between the two different wheels.

Here's how you can approach the solution:

Preprocess the Data: Ensure that the data is cleaned and normalized. Remove any noise or irrelevant data points that might interfere with your analysis.

Analyze the Data:

Visual Inspection: Start by plotting the accelerometer data over time for each wheel. Look for repeating patterns or cycles that correspond to the rotation of the wheels.
Calculate the Fourier Transform: Use a Fourier Transform (e.g., Fast Fourier Transform, FFT) to convert your time-series data into the frequency domain. This will help you identify dominant frequencies in your data, which correspond to the rotation frequency of the wheels.
Identify the Rotation Frequency:

The peak(s) in the frequency domain represent the most dominant frequency components of your time-series data. The highest peak should correspond to the wheel's rotation frequency.
Compare the frequencies identified for each wheel to see if they match or if there are any discrepancies. Differences may indicate issues like uneven tire wear or alignment problems.
Use Cross-Correlation:

To find similarities between the two wheels, you can use cross-correlation. This statistical method measures the similarity between two time series as a function of the displacement of one relative to the other.
This will help you understand how the acceleration patterns of one wheel relate to the other, potentially identifying phase shifts or differences in rotation speeds.
Refine Your Analysis:

Depending on the complexity of your data and the precision required, you may need to refine your analysis by filtering the data, applying window functions to your FFT, or using more sophisticated signal processing techniques.
Validate Your Findings:

Finally, validate your findings by comparing them with known values (if available) or by conducting additional experiments under controlled conditions to verify the rotation frequencies identified.
This approach requires some familiarity with signal processing techniques and statistical analysis, but it will provide a comprehensive method to analyze accelerometer data and determine the rotation frequency of the wheels.

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?